# Get-ItemProperty HKLM...: why can't I find Chrome?

Tags: powershell

I'm using:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
    Select-Object DisplayName, InstallLocation |
    Format-Table –AutoSize | clip
```

but I can't find Chrome in it, whereas I can find it in Windows Control Panel. Why?

Comment: Also look at HKCU, chrome is mostly installed for the current account.

Comment: Shouldn't the command be: `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, InstallLocation | Format-Table –AutoSize | clip` , there is missing a '\' after 'Uninstall'.

Comment: @Paxz It was already there, it just didn't show because it was interpreted as an escape character for the subsequent asterisk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running a 64-bit system, you will need to also search under WOW6432Node. It is also possible to be installed under the CU context as a profile application rather than a System application.

Try this to capture everything:

```
$RegHives = "HKLM:\Software","HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node","HKCU:\Software"
$Apps = @()

ForEach ($Hive in $RegHives)
{
    $Apps += Get-ItemProperty $Hive\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
    Select-Object DisplayName, InstallLocation
}


$Apps | Format-Table –AutoSize | clip
```

Comment: it works except It prints "Google Chrome                                                                                                    C:\..." why "..." ?

Comment: This is because you are outputting a `Format-Table -AutoSize` dataset. When you do this, it transforms that data from its object form into a display object that is limited by its display bounds (column widths), and that's what is sent on to the Clip. If you want the complete object data, you should either output the data in its natural form (`$Apps | Export-Csv -Path \\Path\toFile.csv`) or you can change the `-AutoSize` parameter to `-Wrap` which will wrap the text in those columns to display all of it.